# Finding a function such a partition of a set contains $x$, $y$, $x+y$ for some two elements

Tags: set-partition, stirling-numbers

> Prove that there exists a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that a partitioning of $\{1,2,...,f(n)\}$ into $n$ classes will have some $x,y$ such that $x$, $y$ and $x+y$ all belong to the same class.

I'm very stuck on this... I imagine the answer is something to with Stirling numbers of the second kind but I'm really struggling to achieve any more than this! All I've deduced is the bound that $f(n)>n$ which is pretty trivial really...

Comment: @MSE No it's $\mathbb{N}$, I got lazy with formatting!

Comment: Do you mean $f(n)>n$?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, sorry. My brain stopped working there